# How do you make the LEDs come on for a PS/2 keyboard?

Tags: microcontroller, protocol, keyboard

I'm making a simple console type thing for the mbed with a PS/2 keyboard and VGA monitor. I have a PS/2 library working and can receive scancodes and such. I want to go above and beyond what it allows though and also allow for the LEDs such as caps lock on the keyboard to come on as appropriate.

I know how to do this from an abstract message type perspective and have done this before on x86 PCs before. However, I don't understand how to do it electrically and keeping the clock signal and such in mind. Every reference I've found for PS/2 keyboards just drops to x86 assembly code, which doesn't handle how the PC keyboard controller actually works at an electronic level. I mean, how do I know when the keyboard is idle and I can send a command? Does the keyboard set the clock rate or do I for sending commands? There is only a data and clock line, so I don't understand how to send data back to the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of info on the net? What did you Google?

http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/

Use command 0xED

For electrical connections

http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/PS2Keyboard

The PS2 keyboard is a bi-directional serial line, use same wire to transmit and receive